# Foreach loop in a if statement

Tags: powershell, active-directory

Wrote a small script to check if certain AD groups exists. For some reason it wont loop through the given array. It only writes the first value of the array to the console. When I put a breakpoint on:

```
foreach ($item in $SecGroupNames)
```

I see $secGroupNames being filled with the gives values, can anyone help me out? Can't figure it out for this one.

Code:

```
Import-Module activedirectory
$SecGroupNames = @(  
                     "DB_DATAREADER",
                     "DB_DATAWRITER",
                     "DB_OWNER",
                     "SQL_Public",
                     "SQL_SA",
                     "SQL_SecurityAdmin"
                  )

    foreach ($item in $SecGroupNames)
      {   
        If (Get-ADGroup $item)
        {     
            Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow "$item Exists!"
            return $true; 
        }
        else
        {
            Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "$Item Does not exist, Do something!" 
            return $false;
        }
      }
```

Output:

```
PS C:\Scripts\CreateOUgroups> C:\Scripts\CreateOUgroups\FunctionCheckSecurityGroup.ps1
DB_DATAREADER Exists!
True
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because of `return` statements. It causes the script to return value and end execution in the first loop pass.

If you want to return multiple values from script or function, use `Write-Output` instead of `return`.

```
foreach ($item in $SecGroupNames)
{   
  if (Get-ADGroup $item)
  {     
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow "$item Exists!"
    Write-Output $true;
  }
  else
  {
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "$item Does not exist, Do something!" 
    Write-Output $false;
  }
}
```

Comment: I adjusted my code, though I am getting its not writing the the complete array on my console. It loop 6 times the same result:     


DANNY_DB_DATAREADER Exists!
True
DANNY_DB_DATAREADER Exists!
True
DANNY_DB_DATAREADER Exists!
True
DANNY_DB_DATAREADER Exists!
True
DANNY_DB_DATAREADER Exists!
True
DANNY_DB_DATAREADER Exists!
True

Comment: @doenoe There is a typo in the question `"$iets Exists!"` is that in your code as well? That would make the value not change with each loop pass